# I have no Insert key, how can I Copy & Paste?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

I like to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> for Copy/Paste functions, but this laptop doesn't have an insert key?

Is there another combination for these functions that I can use with only my right hand

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> is paste and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is copy. Also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> is cut.

Are you sure insert isn't just a *function key*?

You can also try something to reassign keyboard shortcuts like [WinKey](http://www.copernic.com/winkey/index.html)